# #1120: Access of Underfined Property SupernaturalHighScores

Tags: actionscript-3, shared-objects

```
//Creates a shared object to hold the users highscores
SupernaturalHighScores = SharedObject.getLocal("SPNHighScores"); 
SupernaturalHighScores.data.Name = "Dean Winchester";
SupernaturalHighScores.data.Score = "200";
SupernaturalHighScores.flush();

trace(SupernaturalHighScores.data.Name);
trace(SupernaturalHighScores.data.Score);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `declare` SupernaturalHighScores:

```
var SupernaturalHighScores:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("SPNHighScores");
```